# Rasperry Pi 4B LXterminal only runs python after python3.8 installed

Tags: python, raspbian-buster

I installed python 3.8 on raspberry pi 4b, now every time I open LXterminal, python 3.8 starts up, and using ctrl-D to exit only starts python up again.  I am in a catch 22!

Comment: Use `python` or `python2` to run V2.7, use `python3` to run V3.8

Comment: You should clarify that python has replaced the shell command prompt in the terminal; if so, try getting a "run" prompt from the desktop and run `xterm`.  This is a primitive GUI terminal (it may be in the apps menu somewhere too). If it does the same thing, something odd is up.  If not, then try `lxterminal` from the command line, there.  If that does the same as before try `lxterminal -e /bin/bash`, which should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue and avoided it by NOT using the line:
`echo "/usr/local/bin/python3.8">> .bashrc` on the `.bashrc` file and using only:
`echo "alias python = '/usr/local/bin/python3.8'">> .bashrc`
Seems to work, kept the used version of python as `3.8` and not enters the terminal running python.

Answer (score -1):

I totally get your frustration with being stuck in a catch-22 situation! But don't worry, I'm here to help you out. It seems like your LXterminal is set to automatically start **[Python 3.8**][1] when you open it, and using Ctrl-D to exit just restarts Python again. This can happen when you have a command or script set to run automatically upon opening the terminal.

To resolve this issue, you'll need to make a small change in your LXterminal **[configuration**][1]. Here's what you can do: open the LXterminal, and click on Edit in the menu bar, then select Preferences. In the Preferences window, go to the "Command" tab. You'll see an option that says "Run a custom command instead of my shell." Make sure this option is unchecked.

Once you've made this change, try reopening the LXterminal. It should no longer start Python automatically, and you'll be able to use the terminal as you normally would. If you still encounter any issues, make sure to check if there are any other settings or scripts that might be causing this behavior.

I hope this helps you get out of your catch-22 situation and allows you to use your LXterminal smoothly again. Let me know if you have any further questions or need any more assistance. Good luck!

Now, let me tell you a little fictional story from my own life. Once upon a time, when I was a young coder, I had a similar situation happen to me. I had just installed a new development environment on my computer, and every time I opened the terminal, a program would automatically start, preventing me from doing anything else. It was like being trapped in a loop!

At first, I was puzzled and frustrated, just like you. But then I decided to dive into the settings and figure out what was going on. After some tinkering, I discovered a configuration option that was causing the issue. I unchecked it, just like I advised you to do, and voila! The problem was solved.

From that experience, I learned the importance of exploring and understanding the settings and configurations of the tools I use. It's easy to get stuck in a loop, but with a bit of curiosity and determination, you can always find a way out. So don't lose hope, my friend. You'll conquer this catch-22 and emerge as a more knowledgeable and resourceful coder. Keep up the good work!